# Passing DataSet to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dataset

I have the following Stored Procedure that receives a `DataSet` as parameter and Inserts into table `Excel`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertInvoice
      @tblInvoice InvoiceType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      INSERT INTO Excel
      SELECT Template, Cust_Name, Invoice_No,InvoiceDate FROM @tblInvoice
END
```

In my code file I am trying to read the `Excel Sheet` and filling the dataset. But problem is I am a bit confused as to how should I send the `DataSet` as `Parameter` to the `stored Procedure`.
This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't seem to work

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + FileUpload1.FileName)));
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
            OleDbConnection oleCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties = Excel 12.0;");
            OleDbCommand Olecmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", oleCon);
            OleDbDataAdapter dtap = new OleDbDataAdapter(Olecmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dtap.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertInvoice"))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblInvoice", ds);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I execute it, it throws `ArgumentException` on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

> No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataSet to a known
>   managed provider native type.

Comment: What happens when you execute this?

Comment: Table valued parameters work with DataTables, not DataSets. Pass the dataset's table as a parameter value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass dataset to stored procedure but you can pass datatable to stored procedure. Follow below algorithm to execute it:

```
1) Create Table type in sql server for the DataTable which you want to pass.
2) Declare input variable for given table type as readonly in stored procedure.
3) Pass that data table to procedure.
```

This only restricts your table type parameter sequence and datatable column sequence should be same.

You can refer this link [Sending a DataTable to a Stored Procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412802/Sending-a-DataTable-to-a-Stored-Procedure)

Or [Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can't parameterize your table name, *basically*.

Parameterized SQL is just for values - not table names, column names, or any other database objects. This is one place where you do probably want to build the SQL dynamically - but with a white-listed set of options or strong validation before you put this table name in your sql query.

It that line;

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblInvoice", ds);
```

You try to pass your `DataSet` to your table name which does not make sense.

Comment: @Nuke TVPs work with datatables, not datasets. Pass the datatable you want as a parameter value